# Как в yii2 наиболее быстро получить выборку 100 записей с пагинацией?

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql

В БД есть болеее 5 000 000 записей. 
Информации в них не много - фильтрация идёт по одному полю, которое является индексом.

Как максимально быстро получить данные с пагинацией в yii2 То что у меня получается работает минимум по 10 секунд.

В контроллере:

```
        $query = Logs::get_msgs();
        $countQuery = clone $query;
        $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count(), 'pageSize' => 100]);
        $pages->pageSizeParam = false;
```

И в моде

```
public function get_msgs()
    {
        $msgs = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select('*')
            ->from('msgs')->orderBy('date');            
        $msgs=  $msgs->where(['type' => '1']); 

        return $msgs;
    }
```

Comment: поле date проиндексировано?

Comment: Да. Пробовал и индексировать его и не индексировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте частичные индексы:

```
create index "msgs_type_1_index" ON "msgs" using btree ("type", "date" ASC) WHERE "type" = 1;
analyse "msgs";
```

В случае, если много данных, то стоит увеличить work_mem:

```
set work_mem = '100MB' -- значение подбираете самостоятельно, основываясь на explain analyse
```

Также необходимо настроить сервер бд согласно параметрам вашего сервера. Неплохой сервис для новичков здесь https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку. Как раз помогло. Таблицу оптимизировал, получилось выполнение за 1,5. 
 random_page_cost у меня стояло 1 - поставил 1.1 - 0,6-0,9

Comment: @Shevtsov Eugene это все равно многовато для такого запроса. Удачи в оптимизации.

Comment: Ну сейчас уже 0.2